# Create a link share feature like facebook

Tags: php, javascript, share, facebook-sharer

I want to create a feature similar to facebook share link in php or javascript

When we share a link in facebook, it automatically fetch the thumbnail, title, description etc from that page.

I want to develop same feature

Thanks in Advance

Comment: It seems like I found one solution.

http://www.achari.in/facebook-like-url-data-extract-using-jquery

This one is a bit slow. But gives the output...

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

```
<a expr:name='data ost.title' expr:id='data ost.url' onclick='return addthis_open(this, "", "page_link_you_want_share", "page_link_you_want_share");' onmouseout='addthis_close()' onclick='return addthis_sendto()'><span>share</span></a>
```

Thanks.